# Search file for a text in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, file-read

I want to search file for a text .I have written the below LOC

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fileread:
    for line in fileread:
        if 'MyText' in line:
            print line
```

My Input file is as below:

```
000001 Mytext Some text1
000002 asdsadsadsa
000003 safasfsaf
000004 Mytext Some text2
```

the output is :

```
000001 Mytext Some text1
000004 Mytext Some text2
```

Later in the day when I run the same code again (meanwhil ethe input file has some data added)

My Input file is as below(with new data added):

```
000001 Mytext Some text1
000002 asdsadsadsa
000003 safasfsaf
000004 Mytext Some text2
.
.
.
.
.
.
010001 Mytext Some text3
```

My output is :

```
000001 Mytext Some text1
000004 Mytext Some text2
010001 Mytext Some text3
```

Is there a way < i can modify the code so that when I run the program for the second time , it ignores values already considered before and considers the below as the only output

```
010001 Mytext Some text3
```

Comment: You'd need to record that data externally somewhere, if you want to do this in 2 separate executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have your program write to a file what line number it has processed most recently.  Then skip to that line when you start.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to record the data in a second text file as you go, using a writer. This way you can communicate between the 2 executions.

Upon the script starting:

- Load those 'existing rows' from a new test file into a list
- Each time you go to print in your existing code, just check to see if its in the list or not
- If it is not, then print it, and add it to your second text file containing values already printed

This accounts for new data inserted in the middle of existing data too.